# MySQL default noise word list?

Tags: mysql

I have a database that is using a full text index and was wondering if anybody knew whether or not there is a list of default words ignored by the match against statement. Also, on this topic is there a way to set a list of words ignored on the index?

By noise words, I mean words that are ignored with the ~ operator in boolean mode.